# Ext4 partition converted to swap. How to recover?

Tags: partitioning, data-recovery

While installing Ubuntu 11.10, I converted by Fedora's ext4 partition to swap by mistake.

Please assist to recover the files and partition.

Comment: if it's converted to swap, then it's cleared. And all info is gone

Comment: It has been formatted. So long information. Sorry mate.

Comment: It's only gone if the swap has been used by a running OS.

Answer (score 1):

When formatting a partition as *swap* only the first few couples of bytes get overwritten, so the data should be recoverable to some extent.

I'd try **testdisk** and in its options mark the partition as *ext4* and try to **list files**.

If that doesn't work, I'd try to recover by using the backup superblock (still in *testdisk*).

If still no luck, then try **photorec** to recover the files at least.

For more info see

https://help.ubuntu.com/community/DataRecovery